# how to open a page on a div tag from another div tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner in html and javascript. I created a link in #top_Bar. when I click on the link I want the page to load on the #All_songlist. but all I see in #All_songlist is just this two words "music.html" not the content of "music.html".   where did I go wrong? I am a bit confused about what does the innerHTML do. I want to do it without useing < iframe > tag.

```
<div id="top_Bar">
     <a href=" file:///F:/music.html"  onclick="load_songlist()"> SONG LIST </a> 
</div>

<div id="All_songlist"> </div>
```

code on the javascript is:

```
 function load_songlist(){
          document.getElementById("All_songlist").innerHTML="music.html";
 }
```

Comment: `innerHTML` literally writes that to the output so onclick you would have `<div id="All_songlist">music.html</div>`

Comment: You'll need to perform an AJAX request to load the contents of `music.html` and then insert that. Do a little research into AJAX.

Comment: putting the html file inside the div tag is not working @redditor

Comment: I edited the link. the page opens fine on another tab. but this is not the problem. I want the page to open on the #all_songlist div tag.

Comment: @Giliweed haha I wasn't providing a solution, merely commenting on what `innerHTML` is. Check out Matthew D Auld's answer - its the best way, you should mark is correct. If you still don't understand it, there are many examples on google.

Comment: :(  I hardly have any idea on jquery. @redditor

Comment: I finally got the solution of my problem by searching alot in the google and it is,document.getElementById("All_songlist").innerHTML='<object type="type/html" data="music.html"></object>'; by this I don't need jquery or ajax (what ever those are! ). :) @everyone

Comment: @Giliweed No, please don't use that method, its deprecated (old fashioned)! I have added a more detailed answer for you which hopefully you can follow. Please mark as correct or add additional comments to that answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This would be easy using the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library. Use jQuery’s [`load()` function](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```js
function load_songlist(){
    $('#All_songlist').load('music.html');
}
```

To add the jQuery library to your current page, add the code below to your `<head>`:

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: You should get started. If you are familiar with pseudocodes in general I think you only need 2 months to get familiar with javascript and jQuery, but if you already kind of know javascripts that period of time can get surprisingly shorter.

Answer (score 1):

As Matthew D Auld answered, you should use jQuery's [load() function](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

As you have had trouble understanding this in practice I have prepared a [JSfiddle for you, click here](http://jsfiddle.net/jXxa7/).

To use jQuery, you simply need to include a link in your `<head`> section. Then you have a script which says:

- `$(window).load(function(){` Do this function when the page loads.
- `$("#SongListLink").click(function() {` When the user clicks on
  something with the ID SongListLink, do this function.
- `$('#All_songlist') .load('music.html');` Populate the DIV with the ID All_songlist with the content from music.html

You finished code should look something like this:

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
$(function() {
    $("#SongListLink").click(function() {
        $('#All_songlist')
           .load('music.html');
    });
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="top_Bar">
     <a href="#" id="SongListLink">SONG LIST</a> 
</div>

<div id="All_songlist"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try an ajax request:

```
function doAjax()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {//IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {//IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
          document.getElementById("All_songlist").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","music.html",true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Markup:

```
<div id="top_Bar">
     <a href="music.html"  onclick="doAjax()"> SONG LIST </a> 
</div>

<div id="All_songlist"> </div>
```

Comment: can you help me by simply telling, how to load a page inside a div tag? I have no idea about ajax. is this  the only option?

Comment: It is not the only option. You could also replace your div tag with a IFRAME, or you could use jQuery and with a simple load function you can do this. If you want to learn, I would use jQuery, if you can't use jQuery, try this ajax option, otherwise, I would go with the IFRAME.

Comment: I finally  got the solution of my problem by searching alot in the google and it is,document.getElementById("All_songlist").innerHTML='<object type="type/html" data="music.html"></object>'; by this I don't need jquery or ajax (what ever those are! ). :) @Hanlet

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
url = "music.html"
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhr.readyState == 4){
 document.getElementById("All_songlist").innerHTML= xhr.responseText
}
}
xhr.send();
```

Comment: XMLHttpRequest() what does this function do?

Comment: @Giliweed this is an Ajax request as well.

Comment: I finally got the solution of my problem by searching alot in the google and it is,document.getElementById("All_songlist").innerHTML='<object type="type/html" data="music.html"></object>'; by this I don't need jquery or ajax (what ever those are! ). :) @everyone